# Adiconar barra de erro no grafico em R

Tags: r, plot

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico mas não estou conseguindo adicionar as barras de erro com a função `arrow`. Não sei o que pode estar errado com o código abaixo:

```
m12<-plot(tq1_mean~time ,type ="p", col = "red", ylim=c(27.0,33))
axis(2, at=c(27.0:33.0))
arrows(m12,tq1_min, m12,tq1_max,length=0.05, angle=90, code=3)
```

Não quero usar o `ggplot`.

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código abaixo usa dados novos, já que os dados originais não foram fornecidos na pergunta.

```
time <- 3:10
tq1_mean <- 3:10
sd <- sd(tq1_mean)

plot (time, tq1_mean, type ="p", col = "red", ylim=c(0, 15))
# desenha o traço vertical
segments(time,tq1_mean - sd, time, tq1_mean + sd) 
# Define o tamanho dos traços horizontais
tamanho <- 0.1
# desenha o traço horizontal superior
segments(time - tamanho, tq1_mean - sd, time + tamanho, tq1_mean - sd) 
# desenha o traço horizontal inferior
segments(time - tamanho, tq1_mean + sd, time + tamanho, tq1_mean + sd)
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: Obrigada, solucionou meu problema